# Remove duplicate entries in a single row

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite table as shown below

```
Name  |        TelNum0 |    Telnum1 |    Telnum2 |    TelNum3
John  |        1234    |    1234    |     1234   |    1234
```

Now i want to update my sqlite database so that finally my DB looks like as below:

```
Name  |        TelNum0 |    Telnum1 |    Telnum2 |    TelNum3
John  |        1234    |           |                   |
```

Comment: You can validate that at the time of insertion.

Answer (score 0):

This database is not properly normalized; you should have a separate table for the numbers, with an 1:N relationship to the original table.

Anyway, to remove duplicates, you have to compare the column values with all previous columns:

```
UPDATE InsertTheSecretTableNameHere
SET Telnum1 = NULL
WHERE TelNum0 = Telnum1;

UPDATE InsertTheSecretTableNameHere
SET Telnum2 = NULL
WHERE TelNum0 = Telnum2
   OR TelNum1 = Telnum2;

UPDATE InsertTheSecretTableNameHere
SET Telnum3 = NULL
WHERE TelNum0 = Telnum3
   OR TelNum2 = Telnum3
   OR TelNum1 = Telnum3;
```